# Combine ActivatedRoute observables with Observables from API requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to combine two observables using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` (my two options until now).
One observable is from the ActivatedRoute's data (`Observable<Data>`) and one is a call to the API (`Observable<Project>`).
[image]

Initially these two were cascaded and everything worked fine. But I was thinking that this might be improved combining the two observables. I know that the observable from the activated route is not completed and it will be triggered every time the user navigates through the app. The second observable is completed when the response is received. The `forkJoin` works on the second type of observables (the ones that are completed) and `combineLatest` works with the ones that are not completed, taking their latest values.

Is there a way to combine these two or is the cascading approach the best way? Thank you!

EDIT:
I've updated the code to fix some small issues and add the array deconstruction.

However, I found that when I refresh the app on the current page the routeData is an empty object, but if I add a breakpoint (in the DevTools tab Source) where the routeData is set it works. Or if I navigate to the component that sets the route data it still works. So I guess a small delay will enable the current routeData to be populated? But why isn't it triggered again when the actual data is placed on the route? *I hope this is not too confusing*

Later edit:
I have 2 pages with their respective components: Asset Management (AssetManagementComponent) and Projects Management (ProjectManagementComponent). Project component is a child of Asset component. When the asset component is initialised I get some data from the API and place it on the `route.data`. Now, when the project component (child) is loaded, I want to get that route data and some extra specific project related data from the API.

The problem is that if I refresh the Project Management page, the code above will result in `routeData` being just an empty object `{}`. But if I go to Asset Management, then to Project Management, `routeData` will contain the correct data.

I've tried to debug this issue using DevTools and if I place breakpoints in each ngOnInit() function it will have the correct `routeData`, even if I directly refresh the app on ProjectManagement

UPDATE:

This is the final and working version:
[image]
Adding the *filter* on the *route data* observable fixed it, it seemes that it triggered once with an empty object and later on with a valid object.

Thank you to everyone for your comments, I've learned new stuff and good practices! Have a great day!

Comment: What's the problem with what you have? You can combine them with the options you listed above. Is the problem with timing or something?

Comment: With `combineLatest`, each time any of the combined Observables emit, it emits the value from *all* Observables. If the `getProjectDetails` Observable only emits once, `combineLatest` will retain the emitted value and re-emit it every time the route Observable emits. I use this `combineLatest` technique often.

 (BTW, if you use array destructuring [routeData, project] instead of just `data`, the code may be a bit more readable.)

Comment: _Is there a way to combine these two_ - but you are combining them already using **combineLatest**. Your approach is already elegant. I'd one more thing to @DeborahK's comment. All the source observables must've emitted at least once before the `combineLatest` starts emitting. So if you're thinking that some of the emissions of one of the observable are missed, you could pipe in a  `startWith` operator to the observable that starts emitting late to kick start the `combineLatest`.

Comment: Indeed, I missed out the _problem_. So, the combining works but the first data is missing, the route observable just returns an empty object `{}`. Also thank you a lot for the deconstructing advice, it's beautiful

Comment: Also there is a bug calling the `processRelatedEntities` function with `this.project` before setting the `this.project`, just found that

Comment: Could you edit your question to update the code, outline the specific issue, and provide more information about what `route.parent.data` is? When/where is this being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, the way I would go about this it to take advantage of the mergeMap.
What is sounds like is happening is the first time your activeRoute subscriptions hits ona refresh it is empty and then it gets the data and sends out a second one.

This approach will filter out all route params that do not have a asset, once it passes the filter we mergeMap that to the next request, just so we can pass it down to the final map where you have both values that should always be populated if that code is reached.

So something like this might work better for you.

```
this.route.parent.data.pipe(
  filter(routeData => routeData && routeData.asset), //make sure route data is there
  mergeMap(routeData =>{
    return this.projectService.getProjectDetails(projectId).pipe.map(project =>{
       return {routeData, project}
    })
  }),
  map(data => {
    // now you should have access to data.routeDate and data.project
     
  })
).subscribe()
```

Hope this helps routeParams can be tricky when you need that value to make another call.
I think that code is correct but its late and I was just recalling that from memory (and google) haha

Comment: The `filter(routeData => routeData && routeData.asset)` was the missing piece. I've added that to the `route.data` and now it works well. Thank you, sir!